# Bulk editing Microsoft Access Reports - Toolbar property

Tags: vba, ms-access, report

**Summary:**
I have a need to modify several reports (300+). The toolbar property no longer exists in this new database (was a port of an ADP, have a custom ribbon to replace it), so I need the modify the Toolbar property in all my reports to be blank

**What I've tried**
Iterating through all reports and changing the property to a string. I've been this with success with essentially the same code to modify a RecordSource and it worked.

```
Sub RemoveToolbarItemFromReports()
    Dim oReport As Report
    Dim nItem As Long
    Dim bIsLoaded As Boolean
    Dim n As Integer
     n = FreeFile()
        Open "pathToMystuff\test.txt" For Output As #n
    For nItem = 0 To CurrentProject.AllReports.Count - 1
        bIsLoaded = CurrentProject.AllReports(nItem).IsLoaded
        DoCmd.OpenReport CurrentProject.AllReports(nItem).Name, acDesign
        Set oReport = Reports(CurrentProject.AllReports(nItem).Name)

        If (oReport.Toolbar = "MYTOOLBAR") Then
            Debug.Print (oReport.Name)
            Debug.Print (oReport.Toolbar)
            Write #n, oReport.Name
            Write #n, oReport.Toolbar

            ' Does not persist
            Reports(oReport.Name).Toolbar = ""
            ' Does not persist
            Reports(oReport.Name).Report.Toolbar = ""
            ' Does not persist
            oReport.Toolbar = ""
        End If
        
        If Not bIsLoaded Then
            DoCmd.Close acReport, oReport.Name
       End If
    Next
    Close #n
End Sub
```

What would be great is if I could either get this VBA code to write changes to my accdb file or if there was a .NET library for reading/modifying Access forms/reports (All libraries that I can find are for reading/writing tables)

Comment: `oReport.Toolbar = ""` should suffice. I would try: 1) add `DoCmd.Save acReport` and 2) set an additional property to make Access register "oh, this object has actually changed!", like `oReport.RecordSource = oReport.RecordSource`

Comment: @Andre Hmm, I will give that a try tomorrow! I like your second bit of advice about setting the recordsource to itself to trigger a "change".